# How can I show the value above only a particular bar in highcharts?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

How can I show the value above the only a particular bar (which was clicked) in highcharts?

```
series: [{              
    dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
    }
}]
```

The above code shows the value on all bars. I need to show count in a particular bar.

Comment: Can you give more details and add your highchart init ?

Comment: @huggilou http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/column-rotated-labels/
this highchart shows population of all places in bar vertically.I need to show population only on particular place (which was clicked).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example of using a points `update` method to achieve this effect:

```
$('#container').highcharts({
    series: [{
        data: [
            // ...
        ],
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: false
        },
        point: {
            events: {
                click: function () {
                    this.update({ dataLabels: { enabled: true } });
                }
            }
        }
    }]
});
```

See [this JSFiddle basic](http://jsfiddle.net/Lbbqyans/) demonstration. Here's [a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gbvzqzh1/) for only label on the last clicked point.